# How to secure web API data?

Tags: python, php, json, api, https

I have a web server with API in PHP and clients applications in Python. Client application sends an request to the server with informations like what OS is client using or what services are running on his computer. The HTTP POST request can look like:

POST http://www.example.com/users/info

And POST data like:

```
{
  "os": "Windows 10",
  "services": [
    "chrome.exe",
    "firefox.exe",
    "calc.exe"
  ]
}
```

I want only my application to be able to send that requests. How can I secure this data against self user manipulation?

Im using HTTPS requests to protect data but Im sure its not enough.

Comment: To what level do you want to protect your endpoint? Are you trying to guard against a rogue user, or a full system administrator? Or do you just not want random bots on the internet hitting your endpoint? "Enough" really depends on your threat model

Comment: The application will be available for everyone so I want to protect it against all cases you wrote.

Comment: First, you can’t stop unauthorized people from sending, so you need to flip the perspective to accepting only authorized payloads, and blocking or discarding the rest. Keys are a common way, have the data signed on the client side by a unique per-client key. Keys are usually hidden from regular users but system admins can still see them, so you have a problem there. But, if a power user sends invalid data, do you really care? Is it just noise that can be ignored?

Comment: Can I protect against power users? I dont want them to overload my database or send fake data

Comment: It really depends on the "value" of sending fake/too much data. Does it earn them something in some way, or is there some sort of external verification that they can then prove to others that they've accomplished the task? If so, it becomes a game which power users might want to play. If you have unique signing keys you can revoke as needed, and you might be able to block by IP at a firewall level, too. If you can have short-term keys with expiration/refresh (like JWT) you can make it more annoying for users, and reduce the time window of the problem, too.

Comment: You might want to ask for more thoughts over on https://security.stackexchange.com/. They know this subject much more than me and might know additional things that I didn't even think of, but I do know they'll recommend a threat analysis and to determine how much you are willing to pay (dollars, CPU, time, etc.) to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is in Python, and any user can read the source code, then anyone who knows Python - and has access to the source code - can spoof requests to your server.

Comment: This is not the answer for my question... I know there is some chance that someone can decompile the code but how to protect it?

Comment: Then you still may not have explained the question properly. Since you are using an interpreted language as the client, the source code is available (even without "decompiling"). This leaves **_no way_** to prevent someone who knows what they are doing from sending bogus data.

Comment: So how can I see the source code of .exe file?

Comment: Oh, is your Python application compiled? While not part of the original question, that would give you more options.